# What are suitable replacements for an sot23 transistor? marking code 1p

Tags: transistors

I was replacing some capacitors on an LG TV circuit board and I slipped and broke a 1P transistor. I have a massive array of old circuit boards but can't find one with the same code. What marking codes would be of suitable replacement?

Answer (score 9):

It's probably an [MMBT2222A](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/MM/MMBT2222A.pdf) (a generic NPN switching transistor), assuming the markings are "1P" (upper-case P). Easy to find, and probably many other NPN types would work too, but you may as well get the proper part.

[image: ![enter image description here]